# Managing access to folders based on roles in asp.net Identity VS2013

Tags: asp.net-identity

I have read several post relating to this issue but cannot find the correct settings.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
     </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

The above is the web.config for the Administrator folder

When I execute the app and try to access this folder I get this error

--- Invalid object name 'dbo.aspnet_Users'--  which indicates to me that it is still looking at the old model but from where??

After quite a bit of hunting and pecking I finally have most of the other functionality of the new Model(Asp Identity EF)  working. I can add and delete roles, add and remove users from roles, list users in roles but I am stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You do not put this information in your web.config with ASP.NET Identity. You should have this in your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

Remove any other references to membership in your web.config. The configuration is set in Startup.Auth.cs file and should look something like this.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }
}
```

You can use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at the Controller or Action level to control access to certain roles.

Comment: I was redirected to another project for a while. This project is my first attempt to migrate an old  project to the new EF/Identity model . It has taken me quite awhile to get everything else working but  this role issue has me stumped. I have everything set up as you describe but it is still looking for 'dbo.aspnet_Users' . I am working my way through the AuthorizedAttribute you referenced. This is not a production application I am just trying to figure out the migration process